# How does the mission distribution of some Crewskills work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have Archeology. Sometimes I can select a mission to gain Artifact Fragments, sometimes not.

How does this exactly work? When is such a mission available and when not? Is it pure luck? Does it have a non visible cooldown?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Patch 4.0 changed this -- all available missions are displayed at all times, so this mechanic no longer exists.

Comment: @MatthewRead, please explain further? This question appears to be asking about when such a mission should be available to begin with, OP only mentiona having displayed it previously.

Comment: @Timelord64 `Sometimes I can select a mission to gain Artifact Fragments, sometimes not.`  Now, that Artifact Fragments mission will **always** be shown and can be selected.  Instead of showing a list of up to 6 missions which are randomly selected from those available (for each level of mission), it will list all of them (so more than 6).

Comment: @Timelord64 I can confirm; patch 4.0 removed the randomization of crew skills.  Now, you see all of them for the selected grade.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I asked about the mass closing in meta, and have been pointed to referencing that suggests we should not be closing questions just because a patch or update makes them redundant. Perhaps these questions could do with a disclaimer, but answering these questions post-redundancy even seems to be promoted quite well.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is randomized every time you load a new area, or when a current mission completes, from a set list containing all types.  There is no timer or cool down; if you stay in one area and do not run missions the list will not change.  So if you want to get a particular mission, you'll have to log out and back in (or zone somewhere fast like your ship to Fleet) to attempt to get it into the random list.  Or you can run quick lower-level missions of the same type to cause the list refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There are a set amount of missions for each type of item (i believe it is 3 each)
When you set your companion to do a mission, the mission will not be available again right away when he/she returns.
It takes some time to reload, i remember when the game just started, going to your ship would reload all the missions that are on down time but i cannot say for sure if that is still the case.

so in short, it has a non visible cooldown.